# Right way with two imageView onClick?

Tags: android, android-layout

The problem is next, when I typed in `ImageView` `mIV_WishItem` "heart", caused `onClick` background `ImageView` `mIV_WishItem`

[image]

The code this buttons:

```
            holder.mIV_WishItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    setFavorites(holder, sectionsItem, true);
                }
            });

            holder.mIV_pictureGoodsItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    SectionsItem sectionsItem = sectionsItems.get(position);
                    sectionItemId = sectionsItem.getId();

                    getDataForItemDetails(mContext);
                }
            });
```

And xml for this buttons

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_200sdp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:gravity="end"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iV_Wish"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/bottom_navigation_icon"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_icon"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iV_pictureGoods_Item"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Please help me find solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to add attribute in your ImageView(mIV_WishItem)  :

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Viewholder item itself focusable, so we need to set focus on imageview. After that we can enable click on imageview.